# ReasonMlでOCamlのライブラリを使いたい

Tags: ocaml, vscode, reason

https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/installation
公式に従いreasonのプロジェクトを作成しました。

vscodeにて、reファイルでOCamlのライブラリを使おうとすると

```
Error: Unbound module ライブラリ名
```

と出ます。
mlファイルでは.merilinに"PKG ライブラリ名"を記入することでライブラリを使用できています。

現在、作成したreファイルをrtop(ReasonMl用のREPL)で実行しようと考えています。
rtopではrequireとopenを打ち込むことでライブラリを使用できています。
そのため今のままでも実行はできるのですが、vscodeでコードを書く際にこのエラーを直すことはできますか。

実行環境

- OS mac
- ocaml 4.06.1
- reason 3.2.0
- utop 2.2.0
- rtop 3.2.0
- bs-platform 4.0.5
- vscode 1.26.1

vscodeでの拡張機能

- OCaml
- OCaml and Reason IDE
- reason-vscode

vscodeでのocaml関連の設定

- "reason.diagnostics.tools": [
  "merlin",
  "bsb"
  ]